# mysql restore command and granting privilige

Tags: mysql

I am having issue by restoring my MySQL table. When I try to write the below command, I am getting the following error → ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'moodle'@'localhost' to database 'moodle'

```
 root@ubuntu:/var/www# mysql -u moodle -p moodle < ./backup/moodle.sql
 ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 45: Access denied for user 'moodle'@'localhost' to database 'moodle'
```

The user "moodle" has already all privileges on the db.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'moodle'@'localhost';

| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `moodle`@`localhost`                                                                                          
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON `moodle`.* TO `moodle`@`localhost` |
```

Thanks for any assistance and support in advance

Comment: Those aren't all the privileges. Just at a glance, it's missing CREATE ROUTINE and TRIGGER and CREATE VIEW and several others. The error says it failed on line 45 of the input file, so what was it trying to execute on line 45?

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin,

on line 45 in the sql file, it is just a table name.

    LOCK TABLES `mdl_analytics_indicator_calc` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mdl_analytics_indicator_calc` DISABLE KEYS */;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `mdl_analytics_indicator_calc` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;

Does it cause any error?

Comment: I suggest you can run `mysql -v ...` to import your sql file, and this will output each SQL statement before it executes. When it exits with the error you show, at least you will be able to see the full SQL statement it attempted to run.

Comment: Note that `LOCK TABLES` requires [the LOCK TABLES privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_lock-tables), but this is not shown in the moodle user's privileges that you showed.

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin, 
now, tried to run the below command to grant all privilege to the "moodle" user, however, mysql is returning the same error code.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON moodle.* TO 'moodle'@'localhost';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'moodle'@'localhost' to database 'moodle'

Comment: You can't grant privileges to yourself that you don't have. That would defeat the purpose of privileges. You need to use another user with privilege to grant those privileges. If you don't have access to such a user, you need to contact your administrator.

Comment: Or alternatively when you create your sql dump file, use `mysqldump --skip-add-locks` so the `LOCK TABLES` statements are not included. Or if you can't do that, use a text editor and remove those lines from your sql file manually. You could also do this with `sed` or `grep -v` or other text-manipulation tools.

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot for your help :) I solved the issue. As you said the user "moodle" does not have all the privileges. I connected to mysql as root user and granted all privileges to the "moodle" Then, I started restore command again and it worked!
Thank you for your time and your  patience !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment discussion above, the issue was:

- The dump file contains `LOCK TABLES` statements.
- The user moodle@localhost did not have privilege to execute `LOCK TABLES` statements during restore.
- Once the root user was used to grant the right privilege to moodle@localhost, the restore succeeded.
- An alternative could have been to omit the `LOCK TABLES` statements from the dump file.